# Using API module internally (ZF1)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created a module called API which serves external clients and returns json data. There are end points like http://example.com/api/user/get-by-id/1 which returns a json representation of the user model. Now I want to use the same api with in our website to avoid duplicate code.

So on my website, if I want to get the user information, I should call api's get-by-id method (which is api module, user controller, getById action)

Of course I don't want to do this over http. So what I am after is, is there a way to call another controller's action, capture the response, and continue with the original action.

```
<?php 
Class IndexController {
       public function indexAction()
       {
            $user = $this->apiCall(array('userid' => 1)); // This is what I am trying to do.
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers in Zend aren't designed to do this.

You can try something like this:

```
    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Simple();
    $request->setParam('id', 55); //param to you API
    $ApiController = new Api_ApiController($request, new Zend_Controller_Response_Http());
    $ApiController->apiAction(); //your API Action
    $yourResultHere = $ApiController->view->result; //get result from View (this is data send to view, not rendered result)
```

But this is not good Zend programming practice ;)

Other option is to create Controller and extend it from `ApiController` instead of `Zend_Controller_Action`, so then you can just use functions like: `$this->apiAction()` and get your results in current View.

But best way is to move code of your API to Model layer and use classes returning data as arrays or objects in your ApiController (which convert them to JSON) and your current Controller (where you can convert them as you like).